# Difficult text formatting problem in Epilog in ComplexPlot

Tags: epilog, superscript

Here's a simple Manipulate demonstration of complex values:

```
Manipulate[
 ComplexPlot[zz, {zz, -2 - 2 I, 2 + 2 I},
  Epilog -> {Arrow[{{0, 0}, z}]}],
 {z, {-2, -2}, {2, 2}}]
```

The user adjusts the Control thereby placing the arrow tip at a complex point z.

I'd like to have text presumably exploiting `Epilog` that reads something like:

$z = 0.8 - 1.1 i$

$\quad = 1.36 e^{-0.94\ i}$

placed in the upper-left of the plot, with the equals signs aligned one atop the other (and small line spacing).

You'll recall from mathematics that if a complex number is $z = a + b i$, then its polar representation is $\sqrt{a^2 + b^2} e^{\tan^{-1} (b/a)}$.

I'd like the original $z$ in the text to be held fixed in place in the plot.

The problems that have stumped me are the following:

- Ensuring the original $z$ stays fixed in place on the ComplexPlot as the values (and width of text) changes.  (Surely there must be a TextAlignment -> Left somewhere in the code.)
- Typesetting the "+" or "-" in the first row.  The naive approach is to include ...<>"+"<>.... between the two entries in z, but then you sometimes get the ugly and incorrect $0.8 + - 1.1$
- Representing the magnitude on the second line ($\sqrt{a^2 + b^2}$) to two-digit accuracy.  I've tried N[Norm[z],2] but somehow I always get five digits.
- Typesetting the $e^{\tan^{-1}(a/b) i}$.  (Because the location of z in the complex quadrants is important for the angle, we should use ArcTan[z[[2]],z[[1]]])

I'd also like to use the special $i$ and $e$ typeset in Mathematica.

The whole task seems an exercise in frustration, and I was hoping there is some elegant approach that avoids all the calls of ToString, Superscript, Text, etc.

---

Here's code that doesn't work:

```
Epilog -> {Black, PointSize[0.02], Point[zz], Arrow[{{0, 0}, zz}], 
  Text[Style[
    "z = " <> ToString[zz[[1]]] <> "+" <> ToString[zz[[2]]] <> 
     "\[ImaginaryI]" <> "\n =" <> ToString[N[Sqrt[zz . zz], 2]] <> 
     "\!\(\*SuperscriptBox[\(\[ExponentialE]\), \(\[ImaginaryI]\)]\)" \
<> ToString[ArcTan[zz[[1]], zz[[2]]]], 20, Black, Italic, 
    FontFamily -> "Latin Modern Roman", LineSpacing -> -10], {-1, 
    1.65}]}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
grid[z_] := Grid[
 {{"z", " = ", Item[Round[Complex @@ z, .01], ItemSize -> {12, 1}]},
  {"", " = ", Round[Norm[z], .01]   Exp[Round[ArcTan @@ z, .01]   Defer[I]]}},
  Alignment -> {Left, Center}]

grid[{1.2345, -2.89123}] // Style[#, 16] &
```

[image]

Notes:

1. Specified `ItemSize` in last column of the first row to prevent columns from moving around as the content size of the last column entries change.
2. Wrapped `I` with `Defer` to prevent default expression formatting in the second row.

We can use `grid[z]` as `Inset` in  `Epilog` option setting:

```
cp = ComplexPlot[zz, {zz, -2 - 2  I, 2 + 2  I}];

Manipulate[
 Show[cp, PlotLabel -> Style[PromptForm["z", z], 14], 
   Epilog -> {PointSize @ Large, Point @ z, 
     Inset[Style[#, 16] & @ grid[z], Offset[{10, -10}, {-2, 2}], {Left, Top}], 
     Arrow[{{0, 0}, z}]}], 
 {{z, {.8, -1.1}}, {-2, -2}, {2, 2}}]
```

[image]

FWIW: You can use a `Locator` as control instead of `Slider2D` with a simple modification of control spec as

```
{{z, {.8, -1.1}}, {-2, -2}, {2, 2}, Locator, Appearance -> None}
```

to get

[image]

Comment: Clean and elegant.  Note, you're missing an "@"  in your Manipulate before `Grid[z]`, but otherwise superb (as always).  I didn't know that the Exp[k] would automatically be converted to $e^{k}$ when rendered.  And yes, the `Locator` is a good idea, which I'll use.  All very helpful.  ($+1, \checkmark$)

Answer (score 3):

Something like:

```
Manipulate[
 ComplexPlot[zz, {zz, -2 - 2  I, 2 + 2  I}, 
  Epilog -> {Arrow[{{0, 0}, z}],
    Text[
     "z = {" <> ToString[z . {1, "\[ImaginaryI]"}] <> "}", {-1.9, 
      1.9}, {-1, 0}], 
    Text["   = " <> ToString[Norm@z]  Superscript["\[ExponentialE]", 
       Arg[z . {1, I}]], {-1.9, 1.7}, {-1, 0}]}], {z, {-2, -2}, {2, 
   2}}]
```

[image]

Comment: Clever use of the dot product.  Thanks!  ($+1$)

Answer (score 2):

Use the third argument of [`Inset`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Inset.html) to specify the anchoring. Use [`NumberForm`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/NumberForm.html) to get two-digit representation. Use [`ResourceFunction["ComplexToPolar"]`](https://resources.wolframcloud.com/FunctionRepository/resources/ComplexToPolar/) to get the polar representation of your number.

A simple example:

```
ctp = ResourceFunction["ComplexToPolar"];

Manipulate[
 ComplexPlot[w, {w, -2 - 2 I, 2 + 2 I}, 
  Epilog -> {Black, PointSize[0.02], Point[z], Arrow[{{0, 0}, z}], 
    FontSize -> 20, With[{zz = Total[{1, I} z]}, 
     Inset[Column[{zz, NumberForm[ctp[zz], 2]}], 
      Scaled[{.1, .9}], {Left, Top}]]}
  ], {z, {-2, -2}, {2, 2}}]
```

[image]

What will probably bother you now is the presence of `×`, representing inactive form of `Times`. Let's do some hackery ...

```
Unprotect[Inactive];
Format[Inactive[Times][x_, y_]] := Row[{x, " ", y}]
Protect[Inactive];
```

[image]